# Repeating an async function 10 times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to repeat an `async` function 10 times with a 5s interval. Here's what I've done:

```
repeat(x) {
    (async function p(x, count) {
        if (cam) {
            await x.foo().then(data => {
                ...
            });
        }

        if (count < 10) {
            setTimeout(p(x, count+1), 5000);
        }
    })(cam, 0);
}
```

But what I'm getting is that `p()` is executed 10 times without waiting in between. Does anyone know why?

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking the function immediately using `setTimeout(p(x, count+1), 5000);` and passing its return value assuming `undefined` to be invoked after 5sec

You need pass the function reference and parameter to be supplied to when method will be invoked using following

```
setTimeout(p, 5000,x, count+1);
```